# How to include caption on web page for gallery using magnific popup?

Tags: html, css, gallery, magnific-popup

I am trying to include a caption on the actual webpage under the image while using the magnificence popup gallery. Using a div and class caption or carousel-caption, I am unable to do so without the images in the gallery stacking vertically one by one. How can I do this?

```
    <a href="img/base/ggg.PNG" title="HELLO" class="chicken">
  <img src="img/base/pop.PNG" alt="remember your alt tag" />
</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.chicken').magnificPopup({ 
         type: 'image',
         gallery:{enabled:true}
         // other options here
         // end each line (except the last) with a comma
      });
   });
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sb4btox7

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/sb4btox7/5/

Comment: Great but my point is I would like "The Title" to display under the image on the page as well not only in the lightbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, have a look at this, I adjusted your function a bit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chicken').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }).each(function() { // Here I chain a loop to each .chicken element
        // Now we append the title inside the .chicken element
        $(this).append('<div class="title">' + $(this).attr('title') + '</div>');
    });
});
```

The CSS:

```
.chicken {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
}

.chicken img {
    width: 100%; /* set it to 100% of it's parents width */
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.chicken .title {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and here's the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/sb4btox7/6/).

Now you can also just add the title directly to the html like this:

```
<a href="http://placehold.it/350x250" title="The Title A" class="chicken">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" />
  <div class="title">The Title A</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the title not a link?

Comment: Wrap your links in a div with class gallery-image and make a few adjustments to the jquery. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/sb4btox7/8/

Comment: Why is your code changing the number of images I can simply on one line from 6 to 4?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The reason for this is because I've set the width to 20% instead of the 11% in your code.